# UIImagePicker StartVideo Problem

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using an overlay button to start video recording on iPad.

When I call [imagePickerController startVideoCapture], I get **"takingvideo activity indicator already cleared"**

The iPad doesn't start recording. The recording starts after calling the startVideoCapture again.
Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)startStop:(id)sender
{
    if (isCapturingVideo)
    {
         isCapturingVideo = FALSE;
        [self.imagePickerController stopVideoCapture];
    }

    else if (!isCapturingVideo)
    {   

        NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        NSArray *videoMediaTypesOnly = [mediaTypes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains %@)", @"movie"]];

        if ([videoMediaTypesOnly count] == 0)       //Is movie output possible?
        {
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry but your device does not support video recording"
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [actionSheet showInView:[[self view] window]];
            [actionSheet autorelease];
        }
        else
        {

            self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = videoMediaTypesOnly;
            self.imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
            self.imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 180;
            self.imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
            self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
            isCapturingVideo = TRUE;
            BOOL result = [self.imagePickerController startVideoCapture];
            NSLog(@"Result Camera: %@", result?@"YES":@"NO");

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with `isCapturingVideo` flag in your code. Documentation says `Calling this method while a movie is being captured has no effect.`.
I suspect that flag is not getting updated properly. you can try force closing( using stopVideoCapture) the video before starting and see if it works.